# Is there a way to write $\dots 2(2(2(2+1)-1)+1)-1 \dots$ in closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, pattern-recognition

It's something like a sequence I'm working with and a part of it has coefficients, which go $3$, $5$, $11$, $21$ and so on. I was wondering if it's possible to find a (closed) formula dependent on say $n$.

The only thing I can contribute is that $(-1)^n$ for the plus and minus ones doesn't seem to lead anywhere (since one has to include the value of the preceding addition/subtraction).

With closed formula I mean a formula where you can plug in your $n$ and obtain the corresponding coefficient immediately, without having to know any of the previous ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So observe that $u_{n+1}=2u_n-(-1)^{n}$ and $u_n=2u_{n-1}+(-1)^n$

Add these to obtain $u_{n+1}+u_n=2u_n+2u_{n-1}$ or $u_{n+1}-u_n-2u_{n-1}=0$

Unsurprisingly standard methods give $u_n=A2^n+B(-1)^n$ and if $u_1=3, u_2=5$ you can compute $A=\frac 43, B=-\frac 13$

Comment: I was so amazed that it works that I completely forgot to ask you how this "standard" method is called—does it have a name? p.s. I think it should be $-2u_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Thanks for spotting the typo. If you look at questions in the recurrence relations tag you will find an explanation or two of why, if $\alpha, \beta$ are the roots of $x^2-x-2=0$ then $u_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ is the general solution to the recurrence.

Comment: @Grantwalzer It's called a "linear recurrence relation" (well really here it's an affine recurrence relation), you can look up these words to see what the general technique is.

Comment: @Naj Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3):

You may find that this is [OEIS seqeunce A001045](http://oeis.org/A001045). In the linked description there is a lot of information, including several formulas, mostly of recursive nature. Among the more closed formulas are
$$a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}\cdot (-1)^{n+k}\cdot 3^{k-1}$$
$$a(n+1) = \lceil 2^n/3\rceil + \lfloor 2^n/3\rfloor$$

Comment: Oh right... OEIS! Forgot about that one.

Answer (score -1):

Try $a_0 = 1, a_n = 2^{n+1} - a_{n-1}$

Comment: I'm sorry, see the edit!